# How to read attribute value using linq to xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, linq

Here i am using below xml file. File name is KMMiddleTier.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"  standalone ="yes" ?>
<KMMiddleTierSecurity>
  <ConnectionKeys>
    <ConnectionKey Key="DB_DEV" ConnectionString="Data source=TTDJS;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TAMSdev;User Id={0};Password={1};"  timeout="200" UserPasswordKey="DBUser"/>
    <ConnectionKey Key="DB_QA"  ConnectionString="Data source=YYSHDJ;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TAMSqa;User Id={0};Password={1};"  timeout="200" UserPasswordKey="DBUser"/>
    <ConnectionKey Key="DB_PROD" ConnectionString="Data source=JSUDHS;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TAMSDB;User Id={0};Password={1};"  timeout="200" UserPasswordKey="DBUser"/>
    <ConnectionKey Key="KMAUDIT" ConnectionString="data source=DISIS;FailOver Partner=LKWSQLTESTWS\LKWSQLTEST;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=KMAuditDEV;User Id={0};Password={1};Application Name='MiddleTier';Workstation ID='Thotsrc1'"  UserPasswordKey="KMAuditUser"/>
  </ConnectionKeys>
</KMMiddleTierSecurity>
```

I am using in windows forms with vb.net

I want to know how to retrieve "DB_DEV" key connection string value into a variable.

Please suggest some code

I want results in some variable as `"Data source=TTDJS;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TAMSdev;User Id={0};Password={1};"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@attrname` syntax to reference attributes, so:

```vb
Dim conStr = (
    From e In xml.<KMMiddleTierSecurity>.<ConnectionKeys>.<ConnectionKey>
    Where e.@Key = "DB_DEV"
    Select e.@ConnectionString
).Single()
Console.WriteLine(conStr)
```

> Data source=TTDJS;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TAMSdev;User Id={0};Password={1};